# How to change color themes in Vim for Windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, colors, themes

I'm a Vim beginner and I would like to change the color theme to a more appropriate one for C programming (I'm using Windows 7, Vim 8.2). After looking for a while, I found the Dracula theme https://draculatheme.com/vim/ but I'm having some trouble installing it.
First of all, I could not locate the .vim folder as the instruction says. I have **C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim** with a _vimrc file, vimfile and vim82 folder. I tried anyway to create the themes and start folder in the pack folder located in **\vim82**, but when I try to git clone it, I get this message: **"fatal: could not create work tree dir 'dracula': Permission denied"**.
Any help?

EDIT: after running the cmd.exe as administrator, I was able to clone the repository. It doesn't work though. I also tried **`:echo $HOME`**, it indicates a vimfile folder in **C:\Users\XXXX**. I tried the same here but with no results.

Comment: I’m one of the maintainers of that colorscheme. The answer below about vimfiles is correct, although I highly recommend using packages or a plugin manager over installing manually.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, vimfiles folder can be located in $HOME\vimfiles or in $VIM\vimfiles.
* More information: `:h vimfiles`

To install a colorscheme manually (without using a plugin manager), you need to download all its files https://github.com/dracula/vim, then copy all files in these directories (after, autoload, colors, and doc) to directories of same names inside vimfiles folders.

To use the colorscheme, place this in your _vimrc:
`:colorscheme dracula`